# Kafka zookeper session not established after creating consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

This is my first time using Kafka. I followed [this](https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os) tutorial.
After starting the Zookeper, I started the kafka server. Next a topic was created and then started the consumer for the topic. This is when the Zookeper logs says

Exception causing close of session 0x0: null

```
2019-01-04 14:11:58,160 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:50480 (no session established for client)
2019-01-04 14:11:59,073 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:50481
2019-01-04 14:11:59,074 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: null
2019-01-04 14:11:59,078 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1040] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:50481 (no session established for client)
2019-01-04 14:11:59,994 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:50482
2019-01-04 14:11:59,995 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@383] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: null
```

I am using Windows 10.

kafka_2.11-2.1.0

zookeeper-3.4.12

Comment: Consumers now don't connect to Zookeeper. Instead of sharing zookeeper logs, can you explain what happens and what you were expecting when you run your consumer.

Comment: You should use this tutorial : https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart. As Mickael pointed it out, you will see differences in kafka-console-consumer invocation.

Comment: I will never understand why people don't use official sites and documentation...

Comment: i was not able to do it in windows. so i resorted to a linux machine

Answer (score 3):

@itssajan

I tried the similar tutorial as you posted in your section https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os, there is a bug in that blog-.

I tried to change zookeeper to bootstrap-server with localhost 9092 and it worked for me.

try this , it should work in windows.

C:\dev\kafka_2.12-2.2.1\kafka_2.12-2.2.1\bin\windows>kafka-console-consumer.bat
--bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning

Answer (score 1):

I cleared

```
/tmp/zookeeper
/tmp/kafka-logs/
```

killed all kafka processes.

Then it worked!